# Resolving contention of two laptops for internet connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

We have two laptops connecting by WiFi to a router. My laptop is stationary in the same room as the router (right next to it). When my wife's laptop is in the same room, both laptops can connect to the Internet. When she is in the adjacent room, her laptop still shows excellent signal strength and can connect to the network, but not to the Internet. In addition, she can connect if my laptop is off.

`ipconfig` for my laptop shows `IPv4 Address 10.0.0.4`. For my wife, when she is in the same room, it's `IPv4 Address 10.0.0.5`. However, when she is in the adjacent room, it's `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address 169.254.102.236`.

I thought the easiest solution would be to use different bands (5GHz for my laptop and 2.4GHz for my wife's, since her laptop is an old one), but was told by my ISP, who supplied the router, that the router selects the band automatically and it is impossible to choose a band manually.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Please let me know if there is some other missing information and how to gather it (network administration is not my cup of tea).

Comment: However, when she is in the adjacent room, it's Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address 169.254.102.236.  .... That is the DHCP not found address. Are you keeping things on one subnet or have you introduced more subnets?  Also see if Wireless Isolation is enabled. You may wish to disable this

Comment: Are you sure the laptops are connecting to _your_ router? (Run `netsh wlan show interfaces` from Command Prompt and compare the "BSSID" to the router's MAC address on the bottom sticker.) No, bands are unlikely to be of relevance, people have been using multiple devices connected to the same channel for _years,_ Wi-Fi is literally designed for that. (Also, if a network is available on both bands, it's the client devices that decide which one to use, the router only offers them both.)

Comment: On your partner's laptop, delete all wireless profiles, restart and try connecting again.  Delete Profile:  Admin Command Prompt.   NETSH WLAN Delete Profile Name="profile name" for each profile.  Restart when done and connect again.

Comment: @John I did not change any settings. Where do I check subnets and Wireless Isolation? Also, how do I list the existing profiles to know their name for deletion?

Comment: NETSH WLAN show profiles

Comment: Could you try moving your laptop away from the router when your other half is in the adjacent room? I know it sounds odd but please try this.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas This did the trick! What does this tell? Also, given that this is the only place we can connect the router to the phone jack, what can we do for a permanent solution?

Comment: Could you answer this question with my answer below? Your best solution would be to extend the phone cord and power lead so you can place the router in another location. For best results, use a complete lead for adsl/vdsl - don't extend with an extension adsl/vdsl lead.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I did not understand the last sentence. What is "complete lead for asdsl/vdsl"? What is "extension adsl/vdsl"?

Comment: it's a two wire rj11 (US) lead that goes from your router to the phone line. you can get extensions, but speed is lost so buy a longer lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your computer away from the router - For reasons I have never quite understood, routers behave oddly when a device is too close to the router, affecting everything else. Don't forget that you are also a source of interference for the wireless signal.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when she is in the adjacent room, it's Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address 169.254.102.236.

That is either caused by another SSID that she logs onto or there's a possible hardware malfunction. I once had a D-Link wireless router that would work normally on extreme close range (<2 m) but cease to do so when further apart. It turned out that some capacitors inside had died and that distorted the signal is such a way that the signal strength was fine, but all data transmission got corrupted. Once I replaced the caps it was running fine again.

Make sure that the laptop is still on the network you intend it to be - run `netsh wlan show interfaces` and check for the router's MAC as commented by @user1686 and/or by looking at the router's status. If it is and the router is more than a few years old, you might want to look for a replacement.

> but was told by my ISP, who supplied the router, that the router selects the band automatically and it is impossible to choose a band manually.

I'd get rid of that crap anyway.

Comment: This is actually a new router (and new model). We experienced the same problem with our old D-Link and I hoped that exchanging the router would help...

Comment: Then I'd try the same setup with each laptop replaced by a third laptop or tablet in turn - possibly your laptop is transmitting noise that is hard to overcome.

Comment: If this is the case, will WiFi extender (which is what my ISP is pushing) help?

Comment: It might, but depending on the root cause it might not. Before buying an extender consider running a cable and setting up an additional access point - extenders decrease usable bandwidth (every frame needs to go over the air twice) while additional access points increase bandwidth (separate radio on a separate channel).

Comment: So, it turns out that if I move my laptop away from the router, then my wife can connect. What does this say about the root problem?

Comment: Have you tried another wireless device instead of your laptop? What happens when you reverse roles of the laptops?